# javascript's drawing with canvas error

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I can´t find the errors in this code. The code is for drawing a figure with canvas based on the input of the user. It throws me 2 errors :

Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function canvas.html?option=circulo:14

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'getContext' of null

```
var my_canvas = document.getElementById("a");
var con = my_canvas.getContext("2d");

var check = function(){
    if((document.getElementById('opcion').value) === 'circulo'){
        con.beginPath();
        con.arc(75, 75, 20, 0, 2*Math.PI);
        con.closePath();
    }else if((document.getElementById('opcion').value) === 'rectangulo'){
        con.strokeRect(100,100,20,50);

    }else if((document.getElementById('opcion').value) === 'arcos'){
       con.beginPath();
       con.arc(75,75,35,0,Math.PI);
       con.stroke();
    }else{
        alert("Ha ingresado un valor invalido");
    }
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your document.getElementById("a") isn't working. Is the id of your canvas really "a"? Does your html look like this:

```
<canvas id="a" width="200" height="100"></canvas>
```

If you do have a canvas with id "a" (id, not class), then perhaps your code needs to be in a window.onload function because it is running before your document is loaded.

Comment: Is your code in a window.onload function, perhaps it isn't loaded yet when this runs.

Comment: I think that was the problem. I put the script after the canvas tag now and it's working fine.